# Why TypeScript gradual typing should stop compiling this valid code?

Tags: typescript

In the following code, although everything looks good but TypeScript shows an error which seems strange:

```
class Sample {

    private value = 1;

    private incrementValue(): void {
        this.value++; 
    }

    private beginTest(): void {

        if (this.value !== 1) {
            throw "bad state!"
        }

        this.incrementValue();

        if (this.value != 2) {
            throw "bad state!"; // ERROR!!: This condition will always return 'true' since the types '1' and '2' have no overlap.
        }
    }
}
```

Why should TypeScript raise such error? I'm changing `value` by `this.incrementValue()`. It seems this kind of error should be an more of an **IntelliSense Warning** rather than a **Compile Error**.

Possibly it is because of the gradual type system, but as it fails it these situations there should be a compile option to workaround this.

Is there any workaround or special compile option to turn this off?

Comment: Should there be something on the right-hand-side of `===` in `if (this.value ===)`?

Comment: @user200783 yup.. corrected.

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you using? I can't replicate the issue with 2.9.2 or 3.4.5

Comment: @Nanotage Sorry there was a typo in the first 'if' condition operator. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While TypeScript's type inference is usually very good at inferring types correctly, the language has limited control flow analysis. The lead developer on the TypeScript team at Microsoft argues:

> The primary question is: When a function is invoked, what should we assume its side effects are?
>
> One option is to be pessimistic and reset all narrowings, assuming that any function might mutate any object it could possibly get its hands on. Another option is to be optimistic and assume the function doesn't modify any state. Both of these seem to be bad.
>
> — Ryan Cavanaugh, [Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)

#### Explanation of your example

In the first if-statement TypeScript evaluates `this.value` as a number type.

Right after the first if-statement, TypeScript determines that `this.value` is no longer of the type `number`. Instead it is of the [literal type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html) `1`.

This is because that any value that is different from 1 (`!== 1`) would have terminated the function. Therefore, any value that doesn't terminate and instead moves on to the next if-statement, must be the exact literal value `1`.

When you call `this.incrementValue();`, TypeScript isn't aware that the function mutates the state of `this.value`. By the time you get to the 2nd if statement, TypeScript still believes that `this.value` is of the literal type `1`.

Because of this, it evaluates the 2nd if-statement the same way it would if you had replaced `this.value` with the number literal `1`

```
if (1 != 2)
```

*(This also throws the exact same error)*

#### Solutions for your problem

As for your problem right now, the simplest solution would be to either:

- Tell TypeScript that `this.value` is a number `if ((this.value as number) != 2)`
- Cast the value to a number `if (+this.value != 2)`
- Add a `// @ts-ignore` comment on the line above so the TypeScript compiler ignores the error

#### Solutions for improving TypeScript's control flow analysis

Ryan Cavanaugh mentions a few ideas for improving TypeScript's control flow analysis:

> - `pure` modifier on functions that says this function doesn't modify anything. This is a bit impractical as we'd realistically want this on the vast majority of all functions, and it doesn't really solve the problem since lots of functions only modify one thing so you'd really want to say "pure except for m"
> - `volatile` property modifier that says this "this property will change without notice". We're not C++ and it's perhaps unclear where you'd apply this and where you wouldn't.

Comment: You're right. Also I liked the `volatile` idea. But the problem is that even if I declare the type explicitly like `private value: number = 1;`, again TypeScript doesn't respect my declaration.

Comment: TypeScript does respect your `: number` declaration, but as soon as you exclude all possible values except for 1 (by doing `!== 1`) TypeScript is certain that the only valid value is 1, and therefore it is changed from the `number` type to the literal type `1`. Imagine if you didn't have the `this.incrementValue();` line - then the TypeScript error would actually be useful, because the 2nd statement would always be true